# Dual of $C(K)$ with $K$ compact

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

What we can say about the dual of $C(K)$, the set of continuous functions on a compact hausdorff space? Can we say that it's isometric to the set of all the regular borel signed measures? I know that if $K$ is only LCH then the dual is the space of radon signed measures. But is a radon signed measure on a compact space the same as a regular signed borel measure?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I think you will need signed measures.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, sorry.